# Error: Unable to resolve module ` react-native-screens` from `node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.js`

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

**Current Behavior**

- After executing app is not installing reporting

```
bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `
react-native-screens` from `node_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.js`: react-native-screens could not be found within the project.
```

**Your Environment**

> | software         | version |
>
> | react-navigation | 3.11.1
>
> | react-native     | 0.61.2
>
> | node             | 12.13.0

Comment: What is the IOS version of the simulator you use?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

well i have solved this by reinstalling / updating these packages.

> npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
>   react-native-reanimated react-native-screens

Answer (score 18):

If you are using react-navigation in your bare react-native project do not forget to also install the following required dependencies:

`npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

...or with expo

`expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any ideas why these dependencies aren't automatically managed by NPM/yarn?

Comment: Check out the [readme](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens#react-native-screens) of react-native-screen. There it is very well described.

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 1):

```
react-navigation-tabs@2.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
```

You have too install it manually.

Answer (score 1):

If this issue comes with ios simulator it can be because of IOS version of the simulator. This happens when using the ios version below than ios 11. Try using ios 11 version or later version in the simulator.

Comment: Did you find a thread on a github or something like that, where this is explained ?

Comment: As I can remember a few members of our team face this issue. When we use the new IOS version this issue went away. I can't remember where we found the solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete the `node_modules` folder
- Execute the following command in the terminal

  ```
  npm install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
  ```
- Install all remaining packages

  ```
  npm install
  ```