# I am new to react native and currently learning how to use react-navigation-drawers

Tags: react-native

After downloading the package, I imported it and tried using it but the server displays the message displayed below:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-screens' in 'C:\Users\hp\gamezone\node_modules\react-navigation-drawer\lib\module\views'

Comment: I resolve that error by simply installing react-native-screens

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Unable to resolve module \` react-native-screens\` from \`node\_modules/react-navigation-tabs/src/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.js\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60051096/error-unable-to-resolve-module-react-native-screens-from-node-modules-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this library as a dependency to your project:

## Bare React Native project

yarn add react-native-screens

## if you use Expo managed workflow

expo install react-native-screens

## Installation

Enable screens support before any of your navigation screens renders. Add the following code to your main application file (e.g. App.js):
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';

enableScreens();

Answer (score 1):

### **Installation**

npm install @react-navigation/native

### **Installing dependencies into a bare React Native project**

`npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

To finalize installation of react-native-gesture-handler, add the following at the top (make sure it's at the top and there's nothing else before it) of your entry file, such as index.js or App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

I recommend to read the Docs of reactnavigation , here is the link : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

for use `react-navigation-drawers` you Should add some dependency package .

first install `react-native-reanimated` and  `react-native-gesture-handler`

for more info : [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-drawer)